# How to get a list of Software Updates that have been applied to my MacBook Pro via Software Update

Tags: macos, updates

How can I get a list of the patches that have been applied to my MacBook Pro via the Mac OS X software updater?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go into the System Preferences -> Software Updates -> Installed Updates.

This does not work from the Apple Menu, but does from the System Preferences.